# sed new lines with \n as part of the line text

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

trying to write a new sed command that will insert new lines before another line.

the code i have tried and is failing is:

```
sudo sed -i '/# onlynet=ipv4/i echo "rpcallowip='$WebInternalIP'\n";\necho "rpcallowip='$DBInternalIP'\n";\necho "rpcallowip='$StratumInternalIP'\n";' $STORAGE_ROOT/yiimp/site/web/yaamp/modules/site/coin_form.php
```

The new lines need to read:

```
echo "rpcallowip=$Variable\n"; example, echo "rpcallowip=127.0.0.1\n";
```

the code above is producing the following result:

```
echo "rpcallowip=10.0.0.3
";
```

So it is seeing the \n as another new line instead of part of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the GNU Sed manual for the `i\text` command:

> Escape sequences in *text* are processed, so you should use \ in text
>   to print a single backslash.

Hence to insert the literal sequence `\n`, you will need to use `\\n`

Comment: good grief the one thing I didnt try!!! thank you